# Grammar parsing of the sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions

From the opening chapter of *[One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wCP2qgXwXdUC&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=%22%20they%20got%20special%20sensitive%20equipment%20detects%20my%20fear%22&source=bl&ots=UDpxbpX1cZ&sig=pVBHISAdJCSW5eCatKxAZVLmQmk&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL99a6tdPTAhUGPVAKHSRmB-oQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22%20they%20got%20special%20sensitive%20equipment%20detects%20my%20fear%22&f=false)*:

> I creep along the wall quiet as dust in my canvas shoes, but **they got
>   special sensitive equipment detects my fear** and they all look up, all
>   three at once, eyes glittering out of the black faces like the hard
>   glitter of radio tubes out of the back of an old radio.

Please could you explain conjugation of the verb detects? Why not detecting? Does it mean *(that) detects*? If so, is such a preposition omission idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not grammatical English.

I suspect the intention of the author was to replicate the less than entirely literate forms that such an individual might have used.

The addition of two words would make the entire passage grammatical - a ***have*** in front of *got*, and a ***which*** in front of *detects*.

Comment: +1  To add to your interpretation,  the sentence is from the beginning of the book and this passage has been described as being surrealistic. The character is under the influence of drugs. See this [literary study](https://books.google.fr/books?id=rAUyBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22+they+got+special+sensitive+equipment+detects+my+fear%22&source=bl&ots=Z9xmtVhKRV&sig=FGN4ypsYFUM2Sdl0lDR7bissJvI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL99a6tdPTAhUGPVAKHSRmB-oQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22%20they%20got%20special%20sensitive%20equipment%20detects%20my%20fear%22&f=false).

Comment: +1 Both reducing *have got* to bare *got* and omitting the subject relativizer are quite common in US speech; they're not so much "illiterate" as casual ellipsis.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes. I did read Mark Twain in my youth. Slightly different to the elisions of a London taxi-driver, but would it be an exaggeration to describe them as "less than entirely literate"?

Comment: @WS2 Well, they're both in my idiolect; but I've sort of passed through Standard English and come out on the far side.

Comment: Well, it *is* grammatical in the dialect it's written in. It's just not standard English. So you could say it's ungrammatical in standard English ...

Comment: @AraucariaMan On that basis, even the joyous gurglings of a new-born babe are grammatical. Nothing wrong with that. It is simply a matter of how we arrange our terminology.

Comment: @WS2 No!!!! Every adult human who hasn't been removed from other humans since birth, and who doesn't have a biological illness or other condition can speak a language. This language, by virtue of being a language, will be a highly mathematically sophisticated and complex system both syntactically and phonologically and phonetically - far beyond our current capabilities to even vaguely understand it. These sophisticated, highly complex and non-transparent systems are not 'better' than others, or 'worse'. There isn't one which is right whilst the others are wrong. They are just different ...

Comment: @WS2 ... As an RP speaker, one wouldn't even vaguley be able to understand the phonological mathematical complexity of either RP or a northern variety of English. RP is transregional English, which is prestige and transregional because it is associated with national institutions and ruling elites, by accident - not because it is better. In contrast, gurgling babies do not have a highly complex linguistic system in place. They are still acquiring it. This isn't because of any prejudicial judgement - it's a fact! Imagine if I said northern English speakers' grasp of phonology was 'infantile'.

Comment: @WS2 Lastly (I apologise), the grammars of non-standard Englishes are--like the phonology of non-RP varieties of English--just as sophisticated  as any other.

Comment: @AraucariaMan I know, I did grow up speaking one of them.